# Find max value and related records too

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have following table.
I want to find out Distributors and assign code for max date transactions.

[image]

so answer will be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MAXDateByDistribuitor := 
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Date of Transaction])
VAR LastDateByDist = 
LASTDATE(
CALCULATETABLE(
VALUES('Table'[Date of Transaction]),
ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Distribuitors])))
RETURN
//Filters on this visual
//Show items when the value:
//MAXDateByDistribuitor is 1 | Apply filter 
IF(CurrentDate=LastDateByDist,1,0)
```

Note that when using a single table, the functions will only return values present in that table. It would be advisable to add at least one calendar and one dimension to identify the distributors.